# Installing Mathematica 11 on Raspberry Pi 1

Tags: raspberry-pi

**Edit:** I originally thought this was a Raspberry Pi 2 but it's actually a 1. The rest of the post has been updated to reflect this.

When I try to install Mathematica 11 on a Raspberry Pi 1 B, I get the following error with Java:

> dpkg: error processing package openjdk-9-jre:armhf (--configure):
>
> dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
>
> Error occurred during initialization of VM
>
> Server VM is only supported on ARMv7+ VFP

Since it looks like Java 9 can't be installed on a Raspberry Pi 1, is it possible to get Mathematica 11 running?

**Update** 
As pointed out by @ilian in the answer below, openjdk-9 is not a dependency. However, when I try to do the install, it does try to install `openjdk-9-jre`, and `openjdk-9-jre-headless`.

> slynch@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt install wolfram-engine
>
> Reading package lists... Done
>
> Building dependency tree
>
> Reading state information... Done
>
> // ...
>
> The following NEW packages will be installed:
>
> adwaita-icon-theme at-spi2-core ca-certificates-java coinor-libipopt1v5 dconf-gsettings-backend dconf-service
>     dictionaries-common emacsen-common fontconfig fontconfig-config fonts-dejavu-core fonts-dejavu-extra
>     glib-networking glib-networking-common glib-networking-services gnome-icon-theme gsettings-desktop-schemas
>     gtk-update-icon-cache hicolor-icon-theme hunspell-en-us java-common libatk-bridge2.0-0 libatk-wrapper-java
>     libatk-wrapper-java-jni libatk1.0-0 libatk1.0-data libatspi2.0-0 libavahi-client3 libblas-common libblas3
>     libcairo-gobject2 libcairo2 libcolord2 libcroco3 libcups2 libdatrie1 libdconf1 libdrm-amdgpu1 libdrm-freedreno1
>     libdrm-nouveau2 libdrm-radeon1 libepoxy0 libexiv2-14 libflac8 libflite1 libfontconfig1 libfontenc1 libgail-common
>     libgail18 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-common libgfortran3 libgif7 libgl1-mesa-dri libgl1-mesa-glx
>     libglapi-mesa libglu1-mesa libgmime-2.6-0 libgpgme11 libgraphite2-3 libgtk-3-0 libgtk-3-bin libgtk-3-common
>     libgtk2.0-0 libgtk2.0-bin libgtk2.0-common libharfbuzz0b libhunspell-1.4-0 libice6 libjack-jackd2-0 libjbig0
>     libjson-glib-1.0-0 libjson-glib-1.0-common liblapack3 liblcms2-2 libllvm3.9 libmad0 libmp3lame0
>     libmumps-seq-4.10.0 libnspr4 libnss3 liboauth0 libogg0 libopus0 libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0
>     libpangoft2-1.0-0 libpixman-1-0 libportaudio2 libproxy1v5 libraw15 librest-0.7-0 librsvg2-2 librsvg2-common
>     libsensors4 libsm6 libsndfile1 libsoup-gnome2.4-1 libsoup2.4-1 libthai-data libthai0 libtiff5 libtxc-dxtn-s2tc
>     libvorbis0a libvorbisenc2 libx11-xcb1 libxaw7 libxcb-dri2-0 libxcb-dri3-0 libxcb-glx0 libxcb-present0
>     libxcb-render0 libxcb-shape0 libxcb-shm0 libxcb-sync1 libxcomposite1 libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxfixes3 libxft2
>     libxi6 libxinerama1 libxmu6 libxpm4 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxshmfence1 libxt6 libxtst6 libxv1 libxxf86dga1
>     libxxf86vm1 **openjdk-9-jre openjdk-9-jre-headless** oracle-java7-jdk wolfram-engine x11-common x11-utils
>
> 0 upgraded, 138 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Comment: I would contact tech support for this, https://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/

Comment: What OS do you have on the Raspberry Pi?  It installed without issues for me on an RPi 1 with Raspbian Stretch.

Comment: @Szabolcs This is with Stretch

Comment: @Szabolcs It turns out that it actually is a RPi 1. I updated the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message means that the `openjdk-9-jre:armhf` package is compiled for a specific CPU architecture and cannot run on anything earlier than a Raspberry Pi 2.

I don't, however, immediately see how that is related to Mathematica. According to the dependencies list for the latest available `wolfram-engine 11.2.0+2018011502`, there is no such requirement

> ```
> Depends: java7-runtime | java8-runtime
> Recommends: oracle-java7-jdk | oracle-java8-jdk
> ```

**Update** Both `java7-runtime` and `java8-runtime` are virtual packages that can be satisfied in several ways, and both have `openjdk-9-jre` as a possible installation candidate.

It's not clear to me why the automatic dependency resolution ends up choosing that particular candidate over the others, but that suggests an easy workaround:

> ```
> sudo apt install oracle-java8-jdk wolfram-engine
> ```

Of course, if you have a preference, you can instead select another Java package.

I'll follow up on fixing the dependency manifest so this problem can be avoided, although I'm not certain whether future releases of Mathematica will support the Raspberry Pi 1.

**Update II**

As [@Szabolcs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/12/szabolcs) points out, with wolfram-engine 12.0.1 and Raspbian Buster (perhaps Stretch too) a more appropriate workaround would be

> ```
> sudo apt install openjdk-8-jre wolfram-engine
> ```

Comment: Although it's not a dependency of the wolfram-engine, it is apparently a dependency of something else. I updated the original question to show this.

Comment: @SeanLynch Thanks for updating the question, I will look into it further. On my RPi I do have wolfram-engine installed, but not openjdk-9-jre.

Comment: @SeanLynch Answer updated

Comment: I just reinstalled Raspbian on my RPi 1, and I bumped into the same problem. It tries to install java 9 as a dependency of wolfram-engine.  Just letting you know that it seems to happen frequently.

Comment: @Szabolcs That's been corrected for 11.3, hopefully to be released soon.

Comment: @ilian More frequent RPi releases!  That's nice to hear. I didn't expect an update before 12.x.  I hope that support for the RPi 1 will be kept for a while ...

Comment: @ilian I am seeing this problem again today. It's an RPi1 with new Buster image ("Raspbian Buster with desktop", Sep 2019). The only things I did after setup were `sudo apt update`, `sudo apt upgrade`, reboot, and finally `sudo apt install wolfra-engine`. This is version 12.0.1 and the problem is still there ...

Comment: @ilian Also, now I get "Package oracle-java8-jdk is not available, but is referred to by another package." if I try your workaround ...

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jre-zero
```

zero is for ARM6